# `does not name a type` error with `namespace std;` and files

Tags: c++, header, namespaces

compiling the code below with `g++ main.cpp functions.cpp -o run` gives me the error `error: ‘vector’ does not name a type`. Declaring namespace at the top of `main.cpp` usually works across all `.cpp` files for me.

main.cpp

```
using namespace std;

#include "functions.h"

main () {}
```

functions.h

```
#include <vector>
```

functions.cpp

```
#include "functions.h"
vector <int> x;
```

EDIT: I appreciate the fact all responders know what their talking about, but this normally works for me. Would the use of a makefile have any bearing on that? something else that I might be missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes but in this example `functions.cpp` has not seen `using namespace std` since you only wrote that in `main.cpp`.

---

Don't add `using namespace std` to `functions.h`, use `std::` to qualify types. Adding a `using..` imposes an unnecessary burden on the user of your header.

Answer (score 8):

You need to qualify the namespace:

```
#include "functions.h"
std::vector<int> x;
```

You have a `using namespace std` in `main.cpp`, and it cannot be seen by `functions.cpp`. That is the root of the problem.

In general, you should avoid `using namespace std`, specially in headers. And if you really must include it in `main`, put it after all the headers.

Comment: I will change downvote to an upvote for anyone who adresses the fact that this usually works for me. Even your answers is only speculative.

Comment: @MattMunson it cannot possibly work for you (in this particular case), because `using namespace std` is not seen in `functions.cpp`. And assuming that `using namespace std` can be seen somewhere can only lead to trouble.

Answer (score 3):

You imported the `std` namespace only in `main.cpp`, not in `functions.cpp`.

You have to qualify your use - `std::vector` in the second file, or use the `using` directive:

```
//functions.cpp
#include "functions.h"
std::vector <int> x;   // preferred
```

or

```
//functions.cpp
#include "functions.h"
using namespace std;
vector <int> x;
```

or (bonus)

```
//functions.cpp
#include "functions.h"
using std::vector;
vector <int> x;
```

> Declaring namespace at the top of main.cpp usually works across all .cpp files for me.

You have a really flawed compiler then. `using` directives shouldn't influence translation units that don't have direct visibility over the directive.

Answer (score 1):

You `using namespace std` is local to main.cpp only. You need to use

```
 std::vector<int> x;
```

in your source file functions.cpp